# R Shiny Server google sheets authentication

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, shiny, google-sheets-api, shiny-server

I am trying to run a shiny app that needs to access google sheets on an EC2 instance but the app crashes on startup due to authentication issues with google sheets.

On my local machine the authentication credentials are stored in a .secrets folder. I have also downloaded the token using `get_token()` and saved it as an rds file and am able to authenticate using the following command:

```
myToken <- readRDS('myToken.rds')
gs4_auth(token = myToken)
```

This works both on my local machine as well as in the command line of the ec2 instance if I ssh into the server. Unfortunately when I actually try to run the app it is not able to start up and simply returns

```
Error in `gs4_auth()`:
! Can't get Google credentials.
ℹ Are you running googlesheets4 in a non-interactive session? Consider:
• Call `gs4_deauth()` to prevent the attempt to get credentials.
• Call `gs4_auth()` directly with all necessary specifics.
ℹ See gargle's "Non-interactive auth" vignette for more details:
ℹ <https://gargle.r-lib.org/articles/non-interactive-auth.html>
Backtrace:
     ▆
  1. └─shiny::runApp(Sys.getenv("SHINY_APP"), port = port, launch.browser = FALSE)
  2.   ├─shiny::as.shiny.appobj(appDir)
  3.   └─shiny:::as.shiny.appobj.character(appDir)
  4.     └─shiny::shinyAppDir(x)
  5.       └─shiny:::shinyAppDir_appR("app.R", appDir, options = options)
  6.         └─shiny (local) appObj()
  7.           └─shiny (local) func(fname, ...)
  8.             └─shiny:::sourceUTF8(fullpath, envir = new.env(parent = sharedEnv))
  9.               └─base::eval(exprs, envir)
 10.                 └─base::eval(exprs, envir)
 11.                   ├─shiny::..stacktraceon..(...)
 12.                   └─googlesheets4::gs4_auth(token = myToken)
 13.                     └─googlesheets4:::gs4_abort(...)
 14.                       └─cli::cli_abort(...)
 15.                         └─rlang::abort(...)
Execution halted
```